# Float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in Python white noise

Tags: python, casting, whitenoise

I'm trying to compute magnitude, phase spectrum and amplitude variation of white noise waveform but I receive an error and I don't know how to solve it...Also, amplitude variation I don't know how to implement in python...A little help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import scipy.signal as sg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = np.random.normal(0,1,1e3) #here the compiler says that it's the problem
E = sg.fft(e)

plt.figure("Bode plot")
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title("Magitude")
plt.plot(np.abs(E))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title("Phase")
plt.plot(np.angle(E))
plt.show()
```

Here it's the error: [image]

Comment: What does the error say? It would be helpful to add it to the post

Comment: @Mehdi added a photo.

Comment: Why do you pass a float as a parameter which requires an int?

Comment: The signature of the `normal` function says that the 3rd argument passed (`size`) must be of type `int`. You are however passing the `1e13` value, which is of type `float`. Replace that value with `1000`.

Comment: @Mehdi can I improve something at my code? If yes, please write a comment to mark it as a solution. Thanks!